# Swift: Initialization of NSTimer was never used, consider replacing with _

Tags: swift

I recently downloaded Xcode 7 and Swift 2.0.  In Swift 1.2 I set a timer with the following code.

```
let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(8.0, target: self, selector: Selector("didTimeout"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

I do not use the timer constant anywhere I just schedule a timer.

I was under the understanding that in order to do this I had to use the "let timer =" portion.

With Swift 2.0 I get the following warning.

> Initialization of immutable value 'timer' was never used; consider
>   replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it.

I've never seen the use of _ before so I just replaced the line above with the line below.

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(8.0, target: self, selector: Selector("didTimeout"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Has not using "let timer" or "var timer" always been ok in Swift or is this new in Swift 2.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you did it is totally fine. If you try it, it will work. 
`_` is something to reduce memory, CPU and storage usage if created things are not needed. I actually do not know why they made it this way.

By the way you do not need `Selector("didTimeout")`. You can simply do "didTimeout:".

Hope that helps :)